# Função do plugin Meta-Box Wordpress não retorna imagem com size definido

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Instalei no Wordpress o plugin MetaBox e adicionei o campo Image Advanced, no arquivo *function.php* adicionei a seguinte um thumbnails personalizado com esta configuração.

```
add_image_size( 'destaque-pesquisa', 120, 90, true );
```

Na página que quero que apareça a imagem inseri o seguinte código.

```
<?php 
$images = rwmb_meta('image_advanced_2','type=image&size=destaque-pesquisa'); ?>
<?php if (!empty( $images )){ ?>
<?php foreach ( $images as $image ){?>

<img src='<?php echo $image['url']; ?>'  alt='<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>' >
<?php }} ?>
```

A imagem aparece na página más sem a dimensão pré definida em `destaque-pesquisa`

Na documentação do plugin Meta-Box informa:

```
$images = rwmb_meta( 'gallery', 'size=YOURSIZE' );
// Ou
$images = rwmb_meta( 'gallery', 'type=image&size=YOURSIZE' );
```